# MySQLで、２つのテーブルを結びつける手法がわかりません。

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ユーザーが質問を投稿でき、それに回答できるというiOSアプリケーションを製作中です。

トップには質問一覧が表示されていて、
１つの質問をタップすると、それに対する回答の一覧が表示させる予定です。(図1)

MySQLで質問一覧のテーブルとそれぞれに対する回答のテーブルを作成しましたが、(図2)
質問テーブルと、回答テーブルと結びつける手法がわかりません。
MySQLははじめて触れるため、見当違いな質問をしているかもしれません。
今回のように、あるテーブルともう一方のテーブルを結びつけるためには、
どのような手法があるでしょうか?
そもそも、このようなことができるのでしょうか?
関連するキーワードなどをご教示ください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: @Yosh コメントするのも回りくどいので、積極的に編集してしまって構わないと思いますよ。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。編集いたしまいた。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

関連テーブル、一対多関係、joins、データベース正規化、データベース基本関連、などで調べられることをオススメします。
データベースの基本概念ですので、どれを読んでもそう外れないと思います。

例えば、下記のようなテーブル構成なら、

users: table
- user_id: integer
- user_name: varchar(100)

questions: table
- question_id: integer
- user_id: integer
- created_at: datetime
- content: text

answers: table
- answer_id: integer
- user_id: integer
- created_at: datetime
- content: text

questions_answers:table
- question_id: integer
- answer_id: integer

質問ID 1 の質問に紐付く回答は、

```
SELECT * FROM answers AS a 
INNER JOIN questions_answers AS qa ON a.answer_id = qa.answer_id
WHERE qa.question_id = 1
```

で求められるはずです

Answer (score 1):

前提として**主キー**と呼ばれる列が必要です。具体的に言うと下の表の`id`列のように各レコードで異なる値を持つ列を追加してやります。

```
id user datetime content
 1 田中 yy/mm/dd 地球は…
 2 太郎 yy/mm/dd ダンゴムシ…
 3 美咲 yy/mm/dd 数学の…
```

子テーブル側には親レコードの主キーを**外部キー**として登録します。

```
id 質問 user datetime content
 1    1 裕也 yy/mm/dd 海が…
 2    1 美咲 yy/mm/dd 太陽の…
```

こうしてやれば質問の主キーに回答一覧を関連付けることが出来ます。

上記の設計はデータベースの機能としてサポートされています。特に主キーは必ず指定するべきです。またMySQLであれば`AUTO_INCREMENT`という主キーを自動生成する機能もあります。